# Why can I not set the width of the first column of the second row on this page?

Tags: html, css, html-table

For some reason I am unable to set and width properties of TD elements within this table, which are NOT on the first row.

For example, in the linked example you can see I have tried to set the width of "Status" by using both the width attribute (set to 280) as well as inline CSS. Neither of these seem to work.

Example: http://www.dnsdebug.com/table.php

How do i manually set the widths of the second, or third row columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you observe carefully, your table is filling 100% of the browser view-port, so, unless you allow scroll bars to appear, your table can grow any more... You may set "status" to 1000px that browser's will still render it as it shows on your link!

To confirm this, just tested setting the width to a lesser value and worked just fine... the problem is really the amount of data inside your table that doesn't allow your "status" to grow as you wish!

Comment: Thanks Zuul, I also just realised this.

I really do not mind horizontal scroll- in fact it SHOULD have a horizontal scroll bar!

How do I set my page width to be less important than the total table width?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think I solved it. Zuul was right about the 100% width, so I just set the table width, and all was well! Thanks!